# GMSMarker not showing on map after adding

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm use button for adding pin on specific location and my map already load and showing on screen. then press button not response even marker create and assign coordinates as well.

```
-(IBAction)addingMarkerOnMap:(id)sender
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
    GMSMarker *london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    london.title = @"London";
    london.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Standard"];
    london.map = self.mapView;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
-(IBAction)addingMarkerOnMap:(id)sender
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
    GMSMarker *london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    london.title = @"London";
    london.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Standard"];
    london.map = self.mapView;
 });
}
```